# "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop" when using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio

I would like to use asyncio to get webpage html.

I run the following code in jupyter notebook:

```
import aiofiles
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def get_info(url, session):
    resp = await session.request(method="GET", url=url)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    html = await resp.text(encoding='GB18030')
    with open('test_asyncio.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        f.write(html)
    return html
    
async def main(urls):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [get_info(url, session) for url in urls]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = ['http://huanyuntianxiazh.fang.com/house/1010123799/housedetail.htm', 'http://zhaoshangyonghefu010.fang.com/house/1010126863/housedetail.htm']
    result = asyncio.run(main(url))
```

However, it returns `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

What is the problem?

How to solve it?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

The [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) documentation says:

> This function [cannot](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L32-L34) be called when another asyncio event loop is running in the same thread.

In your case, jupyter ([IPython ≥ 7.0](https://blog.jupyter.org/ipython-7-0-async-repl-a35ce050f7f7)) is already running an event loop:

> You can now use async/await at the top level in the IPython terminal and in the notebook, it should — in most of the cases — “just work”. Update IPython to version 7+, IPykernel to version 5+, and you’re off to the races.

Therefore you don't need to start the event loop yourself and can instead call `await main(url)` directly, even if your code lies outside any asynchronous function.

### Modern Jupyter lab/notebook

Use the following for newer versions of Jupyter (IPython ≥ 7.0):

```py
async def main():
    print(1)
    
await main()
```

### Python or older IPython

If you are using Python ≥ 3.7 or IPython < 7.0, use [the following](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines):

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    print(1)
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

That's also that form you should use if you are running this in a python REPL or in an independent script (a bot, a web scrapper, etc.).

If you are using an older version of python (< 3.7), [the API to run asynchronous code was a bit less elegant](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-task.html#example-hello-world-coroutine):

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    print(1)
    
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(hello_world())
```

### Using `await` in your code

In your case, you can call `await main(url)` as follows:

```py
url = ['url1', 'url2']
result = await main(url)

for text in result:
    pass # text contains your html (text) response
```

This change to recent versions of IPython makes notebook code simpler and more intuitive for beginers.

### Further notices

Few remarks that might help you in different use cases.

#### Jupyter vs. IPython caution

There is a [slight difference](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/autoawait.html#difference-between-terminal-ipython-and-ipykernel) on how Jupyter uses the loop compared to IPython.

> [...] IPykernel having a persistent `asyncio` loop running, while Terminal IPython starts and stops a loop for each code block.

This can lead to [unexpected issues](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11303/).

#### Google Colab

In the past, Google colab required you to do more complex loop manipulations like presented in some other answers here. Now plain `await main()` should just work like in IPython ≥ 7.0 (tested on Colab version `2023/08/18`).

#### Python REPL

You can also run the python REPL using the `asyncio` concurrent context. As explained in [`asyncio`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html):

```py
$ python -m asyncio
asyncio REPL ...
Use "await" directly instead of "asyncio.run()".
>>> import asyncio
>>> await asyncio.sleep(10, result='hello')
'hello'
```

The `asyncio` REPL [should be available for python ≥ 3.8.1](https://bugs.python.org/issue37028).

#### When does `asyncio.run` matters and why?

Older versions of IPython were running in a synchronous context, which is why calling [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run) was mandatory.

The `asyncio.run` function allows to run asynchronous code from a synchronous context by doing the following:

- starts an event loop,
- runs the async function passed as argument in this (new) event loop,
- stops the event loop once the function returned

In more technical terms (notice how the function is called a [**coroutine**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine)):

> This function runs the passed coroutine, taking care of managing the asyncio event loop, finalizing asynchronous generators, and closing the threadpool.

#### What happen when using `await` in synchronous context?

If you happen to use `await` in a synchronous context you would get the one of the following errors:

- `SyntaxError: 'await' outside function`
- `SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function`

In that case that means you need to use `asyncio.run(main())` instead of `await main()`.

Comment: Thank you, cglacet. However, there is a warning : `c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:29: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited`

Comment: That's probably because you called `main(url)` instead of `await main(url)`.

Comment: Is there a way to have a code snippet that works both inside and outside of Jupyter?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but I'm not sure you would really want that anyway. Maybe ask this as a separate question and see if people have ideas on whether it's possible or desirable.

Comment: Interestingly, when I run the above in jupyter,  I get: SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Comment: Maybe try to upgrade jupyter, older versions do not work the same way.

Comment: @Luca i used the wait it and it worked for me ( in a very simple program to just sign in and receive a token from telethon )

Comment: solved my issue in vs code Jupyter notebook

Comment: Was the error the exact same? It may be worth to add the vscode tag to the question if that's the case (I think more and more people will use the extension as it improves).

Answer (score 70):

To add to `cglacet`'s answer - if one wants to detect whether a loop is running and adjust automatically (ie run `main()` on the existing loop, otherwise `asyncio.run()`), here is a snippet that may prove useful:

```py
# async def main():
#     ...

try:
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
except RuntimeError:  # 'RuntimeError: There is no current event loop...'
    loop = None

if loop and loop.is_running():
    print('Async event loop already running. Adding coroutine to the event loop.')
    tsk = loop.create_task(main())
    # ^-- https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-object
    # Optionally, a callback function can be executed when the coroutine completes
    tsk.add_done_callback(
        lambda t: print(f'Task done with result={t.result()}  << return val of main()'))
else:
    print('Starting new event loop')
    result = asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Nice, indeed adding a callback here is probably the only way of getting the result back. That would probably be interesting to have this code in a function so you would only have to call something like `run(main(*args, **kwargs))`. The function could also make sure you get your output back, not sure that's really simple tho (because of the callback).

Comment: This is an intriguing solution. How would you get `t.result()` in a variable instead of printing it out?

Comment: @alec_djinn no immediate easy answer (at least not from *within the sync code*), since introducing a blocking method in the current thread ie. in sync code (such as `Queue.get()`, with a `Queue.put(t.result())` in callback) would also block the existing async loop from running (in current thread), thus no result would arrive -> deadlock. If you're in a Jupyter NB you could still use a messaging system and manually check for the result (in non-blocking manner). Note using `time.sleep()` in sync code (current thread) doesn't help since it would also pause the existing async loop.

Comment: @JeanMonet this is awesome! Deserve more upvotes.

Comment: This doesn't block execution after `tsk.add_done_callback(...)` and that's the problem if later code depends on result.

Comment: @VishalSahu you probably need to structure your code differently. If you block code here to wait for result, the async loop gets blocked as well.

Answer (score 42):

Just use this:

https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

Comment: The docs for `nest_asyncio` mention a [issue report with asyncio](https://bugs.python.org/issue22239) where its explicitly stated that this is no intended behaviour for asyncio. So I would consider `nest_asyncio` a big fat hack which I wouldn't trust with in my codebase to not break everything with a new Python version.

Comment: Another issue is that nest_asyncio requires Python 3.5 or above, which is not helpful to me as I am stuck on Python 2.7.

Comment: this allowed me to solve the issue for the imported code (where you can't change it yourself)

Comment: This worked so well fixing a imported asyncio issue, thanks alot

Answer (score 29):

Combining the methods from Pankaj Sharma and Jean Monet, I wrote the following snippet that acts as asyncio.run (with slightly different syntax), but also works within a Jupyter notebook.

```
import threading

class RunThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, func, args, kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.result = None
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.result = asyncio.run(self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs))

def run_async(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = None
    if loop and loop.is_running():
        thread = RunThread(func, args, kwargs)
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        return thread.result
    else:
        return asyncio.run(func(*args, **kwargs))
```

Usage:

```
async def test(name):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return f"hello {name}"

run_async(test, "user")  # blocks for 5 seconds and returns "hello user"
```

Comment: thank you for this clever solution. Do you have any suggestion for "asyncio attached to a different loop" error? Inside child loops i need to use 2 coroutines from main loop.

Answer (score 8):

To add to existing answers, a somewhat shorter version:

- Without external libraries
- Allows running inside or outside of a Jupyter Notebook
- Allows fetching the return value

```py
try:
    asyncio.get_running_loop() # Triggers RuntimeError if no running event loop
    # Create a separate thread so we can block before returning
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(1) as pool:
        result = pool.submit(lambda: asyncio.run(myfunc())).result()
except RuntimeError:
    result = asyncio.run(myfunc())
```

Note: if `myfunc`'s internals throw a `RuntimeError` and was run in the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, `myfunc` will be re-run in the `except` clause. So if your `myfunc` can throw a `RuntimeError`, consider checking for the `RuntimeError`'s cause within the `except` clause

Comment: Attention: calling `result()` on the `Future` returned after submitting the lambda to the pool may raise `RuntimeError` on its own, depending on what is inside `myfunc`. This is then caught and causes running `myfunc()` again in the default event loop.

Answer (score 5):

I found the [`unsync`](https://github.com/alex-sherman/unsync) package useful for writing code that behaves the same way in a Python script and the Jupyter REPL.

```py
import asyncio
from unsync import unsync


@unsync
async def demo_async_fn():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    return "done!"

print(demo_async_fn().result())
```

Answer (score 4):

Slight simplification of the solution by Mark:

```py
import threading

class RunThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, coro):
        self.coro = coro
        self.result = None
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.result = asyncio.run(self.coro)


def run_async(coro):
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = None
    if loop and loop.is_running():
        thread = RunThread(coro)
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        return thread.result
    else:
        return asyncio.run(coro)
```

Use `run_async()` like `async.run()`, i.e., `run_async(test("user"))`.

Answer (score 1):

As cglacet mentioned that documentation says

> This function cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is
>   running in the same thread.

You can use another thread i.e -

```
class ResolveThread(threading.Thread):
            def __init__(self,result1,fun,url):
                self.result1= result1
                self.fun = fun
                self.url = url
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            def run(self):
                result1[0] = asyncio.run(self.fun(self.url))


result1 = [None]
sp = ResolveThread(result1)
sp.start()
sp.join() # connect main thread
result = result1[0]
```