# "RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop" in Spyder

Tags: python, python-asyncio, spyder, python-3.7

I am trying to learn about asyncio for a websockets client. Every piece of code I try gets the following error:

> RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

I have tried the most simple code and it always gives that RuntimeError. I tried installing the full anaconda distribution again, etc, and can´t find what the problem might be.

I am using Spyder 3.3.3 with Python 3.7.3

An example of code that should work:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('world')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Error message:

```
File "C:\Users\jmart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
  execfile(filename, namespace)
File "C:\Users\jmart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
  exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
File "C:/Users/jmart/Documents/asynk2.py", line 8, in <module>
  asyncio.run(main())
File "C:\Users\jmart\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 34, in run
  "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

Comment: Did you try to run the code form a terminal typing `python3.7 asynk2.py`? My guess is that Spyder is using an event loop to run its python console/interpreter which causes this issue...

Comment: Many thanks, that seems to be the issue, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Adding `import nest_asyncio` and `nest_asyncio.apply()` seems to be one solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop" when using Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55409641/asyncio-run-cannot-be-called-from-a-running-event-loop-when-using-jupyter-no)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's [a known problem](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3397) related to IPython.

[One way](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3397#issuecomment-419386811) as you already found is to use `nest_asyncio`:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

[The other one](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3397#issuecomment-383452306) is to install older version of `tornado`:

```
pip3 install tornado==4.5.3
```

Comment: The first solution seems to give some running problems for me, installing the older version of tornado seems to work perfectly!

Comment: Beware, nested run calls will starve out loops.  This monkey patch is very fragile on python / stdlib upgrades.

Comment: Is there any reason for not simply using [`await main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55409674/1720199) with spyder?

Comment: I've started having problems after upgrading databricks cluster to runtime 11.3 (it informs 3.9.5 on sys.version). My code was working perfectly on 10.5 version. Just added the nest_asyncio as above at the start of my notebook and it's resolved.

Answer (score 11):

### **Problem origin**

Spyder runs its own event loop

```py
print(asyncio.get_running_loop().is_running()) 
Returns: True
```

but only one is allowed per thread

> [cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is running in the
> same thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run)

That is why, when we try to create a new event loop with 
`asyncio.run(main())` it gives us an error: 
`RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

### **Solution**

Except what already proposed with nest_asyncio and tornado I came up with

1. Attach to an existing Spyder thread event loop by creating a new task

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('Hello world!')

asyncio.create_task(main())
```

2. Create new thread (by executing in external terminal) which allows to run our own event loop.
   Top menu *Run* -> *Run configuration per file...* -> *Execute in the external system terminal*
   [image]

Now the code runs in new terminal and works

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('Hello world!')
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: This is definetly the better answer. Perfect would be a interpreter-independent version with `try: ....create_task(main()) except RuntimeError: asyncio.run(main())`. This works fine in Spyder, but still produces some warnings in python shell :(

Comment: `task = create_task(main())` swallows exceptions. So I added `task.add_done_callback(lambda task: task.result())`.