# how to repeat/execute a coroutine at the same time using asyncio.gather?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

I've tried to run a coroutine twice at the same time(below) but I got a RuntimeError: This event loop is already running. unfortunately I fund noting helpful from google.

I appreciate your help in advance : )

```py
async def _compare(max_bid, min_ask):
            if max_bid > min_ask:
                print('example')            

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
                _compare(a_max_bid, b_min_ask),
                _compare(b_max_bid, a_min_ask)
            ))
```

```sh
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

Comment: How exactly are you running this program? If you are typing it into an interactive environment, which one?

Comment: If you're using IPython, solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56156310/1113207).

Comment: Your code is working for me on python3.7, so it must be indeed your environment.