# Wait for asyncio.create_task to get results in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, spyder

I am trying to understand how asynchronous calls run in python using Spyder IDE.

I have written the following code:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

async def factorial(number):
    f = 1
    for i in range(2, number + 1):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        f *= i
    print(f"Task {number}: factorial({number}) = {f}")
    return f

async def main():
    # Schedule three calls *concurrently*:
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    L =  [await loop.run_in_executor(executor, factorial, i) for i in range(2,5)]
    L = await asyncio.gather(*L)
        

    print(L)
    return(L)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = asyncio.create_task(main())
    if a.done():
        res = a.result()
        print("RESULT:",res)
    print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
```

I was hoping to get results from asyncio,create_task but from Spyder´s console a get the folowing results:

In[1] :

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Task 2: factorial(2) = 2

Task 3: factorial(3) = 6

Task 4: factorial(4) = 24

[2, 6, 24]

Looks like print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA") is runing before I get the results from asyncio.create_task(), and actually I don´t see the results printed on screen print("RESULT:",res).

What I am missing?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be specific to spyder, where I assume you encountered a problem where `asyncio.run()` could not be used because of an already existing event loop. Normally you would do this:

```
res = asyncio.run(main())
print("RESULT:", res)
```

But since this apparently does not work for spyder, we need other options.

#### First option

What currently happens with `a = asyncio.create_task(main())` is that you are essentially creating a task that you are not awaiting. One option would be to just move all of the code apart from the `asyncio.create_task(main())` to `main()`, that's kind of the point of the function. You are basically already printing the result with `print(L)`, so do you need the other print?

#### Second option

Like said, normally you would `await` anything that you create with `create_task`. Now you are checking the result once and then giving up, which is why the final print executes too early. Since await won't work without being in an `async` function already, you need something else, maybe a while loop:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = asyncio.create_task(main())

    while not a.done():
        asyncio.sleep(1)
    
    res = a.result()
    print("RESULT:",res)
```

#### Third option

Third option comes from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65696398/6845813

You would change the configuration of spyder to run the file in an external terminal, in which case the normal workflow would work:

```
asyncio.run(main())
print("RESULT":, res)
```

I thin this option is the best for portability within editors, but that's just my preference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried the thrid option.  if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main()). But I still get the following error message: "RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop". On Spyder Run>Configuration Per File> Selected Run File With Custom Configuration > Execute in external system terminal > Run

Comment: Interesting. Maybe that answer is outdated then.