# Python code runs as script and in ipython, but throws error in jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to run a snippet of my code in Jupyter notebook, but it's failing. However the same snippet runs as script as well as a python script.

code :

```py
import asyncio

async def a_square(x):
    print(f'Asynchronously squaring {x}!')
    return x ** 2


asyncio.run(a_square(2))
```

Error in Jupyter

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e2feaf9936d2> in <module>
      5     return x ** 2
      6 
----> 7 asyncio.run(a_square(2))

/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py in run(main, debug)
     31     """
     32     if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
---> 33         raise RuntimeError(
     34             "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")
     35 

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

Python path, version are same for all. The following statements gave same output for Jupyter, Ipython as well as when executed from script.

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)
```

output :

```
/usr/bin/python3
3.8.5 (default, Jul 27 2020, 08:42:51) 
[GCC 10.1.0]
```

Comment: Here's a better answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55409674/12479639 Basically as the error states, Jupyter is already running an event loop and you need only to `await` your function.

Comment: It seems like Jupyter is already running an event loop of it's own then. For the new ascynio, the asyncio.run removes the necessity of creating a new loop, something which i wanted to try.