# %time await main() throws SyntaxError: 'await' outside function in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I try to count time using `%time` in Jupyter-notebook, and some SyntaxError just makes me confused.
Here is a simple code that can demonstrate the problem

```
import asyncio
async def main():
    print(1)
    
%time asyncio.run(main())
```

which throws `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

according to [asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55409641/asyncio-run-cannot-be-called-from-a-running-event-loop), I change the code like this

```
import asyncio
async def main():
    print(1)
    
%time await main()
```

and it throws `SyntaxError: 'await' outside function`

when I remove the `%time` part the code works fine.

Did jupyter not support `%time` with asyncio functions?

Comment: Your first attempt would have worked in terminal IPython, but [not in a notebook kernel](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/autoawait.html#using-autoawait-in-a-notebook-ipykernel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ipython (therefore juypter) doesn't support magics interoperability with async.

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/autoawait.html#effects-on-magics

> A couple of magics (%%timeit, %timeit, %%time, %%prun) have not yet been
> updated to work with asynchronous code and will raise syntax errors
> when trying to use top-level await. We welcome any contribution to
> help fix those, and extra cases we haven’t caught yet. We hope for
> better support in Core Python for top-level Async code.