# I'm trying to make an async function and came across this error saying 'asyncio.run() cannot be called from an running event loop'

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, whois

```
url1=['www.google.com', 'www.youtube.com', 'www.facebook.com']
async def dnsRec(url):
    async with whois.whois(urlparse(url).netloc) as response:
        domain_detail = response.json()
        return domain_detail
    
async def main():
    task = [dnsRec(i) for i in url1]
    await asyncio.gather(*task)
    
def func():
    asyncio.run(main())

func()
```

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect it should be `await dnsRec(i)`

Comment: This looks helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55409641/asyncio-run-cannot-be-called-from-a-running-event-loop

Comment: Especially the part about Jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be that you are already using a framework such as FastAPI which already creates an async queue. Therefore you need to add your async function to the existing loop. For instance:

```py
# ... previous code

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def func():
    asyncio.run(main())

loop.create_task(func())
```