# XRPL-py: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio, xrp

I tried to execute the following example Python code in Jupyter Notebook v7.0.6:

https://xrpl-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/source/snippets.html

```
from xrpl.clients import JsonRpcClient
from xrpl.models import Ledger, Tx

# References
# - https://xrpl.org/look-up-transaction-results.html
# - https://xrpl.org/parallel-networks.html#parallel-networks
# - https://xrpl.org/tx.html

# Create a client to connect to the main network
client = JsonRpcClient("https://xrplcluster.com/")

# Create a Ledger request and have the client call it
ledger_request = Ledger(ledger_index="validated", transactions=True)
ledger_response = client.request(ledger_request)
```

The code fails on the last line with the following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/genericpath.py:77: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'JsonRpcBase.request_impl' was never awaited
  m = tuple(map(os.fspath, m))
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/genericpath.py:77: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'WebsocketClient.request_impl' was never awaited
  m = tuple(map(os.fspath, m))
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[47], line 2
      1 ledger_request = Ledger(ledger_index="validated", transactions=True)
----> 2 ledger_response = client.request(ledger_request)
      3 #ledger_response2 = client2.request(ledger_request)
      4 
      5 #print(ledger_response)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xrpl/clients/sync_client.py:28, in SyncClient.request(self, request)
     18 def request(self: SyncClient, request: Request) -> Response:
     19     """
     20     Makes a request with this client and returns the response.
     21 
   (...)
     26         The Response for the given Request.
     27     """
---> 28     return asyncio.run(self.request_impl(request))

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py:33, in run(main, debug)
      9 """Execute the coroutine and return the result.
     10 
     11 This function runs the passed coroutine, taking care of
   (...)
     30     asyncio.run(main())
     31 """
     32 if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
---> 33     raise RuntimeError(
     34         "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")
     36 if not coroutines.iscoroutine(main):
     37     raise ValueError("a coroutine was expected, got {!r}".format(main))

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

Note the same error occurs if the client was a Websocketclient:

```
from xrpl.clients import WebsocketClient
```

I see many posts regarding the same error on SO but I am not the author of xrpl-py and can't make the appropriate changes.

The solution offered is as follows:

[asyncio.run error when using Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55409641/asyncio-run-cannot-be-called-from-a-running-event-loop-when-using-jupyter-no?rq=2)

Error message when using a solution offered:

```
In [15]: import asyncio
    ...: from xrpl.clients import JsonRpcClient
    ...: from xrpl.models import Ledger
    ...: 

In [16]: async def fetch_ledger_data():
    ...:     client = JsonRpcClient("https://s1.ripple.com:51234")
    ...: 
    ...:     ledger_request = Ledger(ledger_index="validated", transactions=True)
    ...: 
    ...:     ledger_response = await client.request(ledger_request)
    ...: 
    ...:     return ledger_response
    ...: 

In [17]: run -m fetch_ledger_data
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('run', '-m fetch_ledger_data')

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2456, in InteractiveShell.run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2454     kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
   2455 with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2456     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2458 # The code below prevents the output from being displayed
   2459 # when using magics with decorator @output_can_be_silenced
   2460 # when the last Python token in the expression is a ';'.
   2461 if getattr(fn, magic.MAGIC_OUTPUT_CAN_BE_SILENCED, False):

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py:708, in ExecutionMagics.run(self, parameter_s, runner, file_finder)
    706 if "m" in opts:
    707     modulename = opts["m"][0]
--> 708     modpath = find_mod(modulename)
    709     if modpath is None:
    710         msg = '%r is not a valid modulename on sys.path'%modulename

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/utils/module_paths.py:62, in find_mod(module_name)
     40 """
     41 Find module `module_name` on sys.path, and return the path to module `module_name`.
     42 
   (...)
     59     depending on above conditions.
     60 """
     61 spec = importlib.util.find_spec(module_name)
---> 62 module_path = spec.origin
     63 if module_path is None:
     64     if spec.loader in sys.meta_path:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'
```

**UPDATE-2**: This is the error message I get using the updated solution. At this point I am wondering whether the **xrpl-py** library can even be used with **IPython (Jupyter Notebooks)**.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[76], line 1
----> 1 response = await fetch_ledger_data()

Cell In[75], line 8, in fetch_ledger_data()
      6 client = JsonRpcClient("https://s1.ripple.com:51234")
      7 ledger_request = Ledger(ledger_index="validated", transactions=True)
----> 8 ledger_response = await client.request(ledger_request)
      9 return ledger_response

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xrpl/clients/sync_client.py:28, in SyncClient.request(self, request)
     18 def request(self: SyncClient, request: Request) -> Response:
     19     """
     20     Makes a request with this client and returns the response.
     21 
   (...)
     26         The Response for the given Request.
     27     """
---> 28     return asyncio.run(self.request_impl(request))

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py:33, in run(main, debug)
      9 """Execute the coroutine and return the result.
     10 
     11 This function runs the passed coroutine, taking care of
   (...)
     30     asyncio.run(main())
     31 """
     32 if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
---> 33     raise RuntimeError(
     34         "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")
     36 if not coroutines.iscoroutine(main):
     37     raise ValueError("a coroutine was expected, got {!r}".format(main))

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is within an already running event loop, it's common thing when you're running code in the env like Jupyter Notebook, and the problem within that is that it already has an event loop running in the background - therefore `asyncio.run()` itself is made to run a coroutine in a fresh event loop, so that means it can't be used if there's already an event loop in progress...

Now, I know that `xrpl-py` library functions are `async`, you will need to run them in an async context, so on Jupyter notebook - by using `%run` to handle this. Your approach would be:

1. Define an async function
2. Use %run to run the async func

Something like this should be working fine:

```
import asyncio
from xrpl.clients import JsonRpcClient
from xrpl.models import Ledger

async def fetch_ledger_data():
    client = JsonRpcClient("https://xrplcluster.com/")

    ledger_request = Ledger(ledger_index="validated", transactions=True)

    ledger_response = await client.request(ledger_request)

    return ledger_response

# To run it you'd do it like this:
# %run -m fetch_ledger_data
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Okay, since I now got a little bit of clue of what's happening here, let's re-arange the approach, as I think I confused OP with `%run` command. The error you get, while using `%run -m fetch_ledger_data` is originating by cause that Jupyter itself is trying to access the module named `fetch_ledger_data` - but it can't (it doesn't exist as a separate module). Therefore or should I say: "that being said", `%run` - **command is used to execute python scripts, and not functions defined.**

To address issue and provide more tailored up answer, in order for you to execute `asynchronous` code, you should be using `await` keyword directly in a `notebook cell.` [What is Notebook Cell](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebook.html).
Therefore, define `async` func, as we did before, then you place this in a cell and execute it to define the function.

```
import asyncio
from xrpl.clients import JsonRpcClient
from xrpl.models import Ledger

async def fetch_ledger_data():
    client = JsonRpcClient("https://xrplcluster.com/")
    ledger_request = Ledger(ledger_index="validated", transactions=True)
    ledger_response = await client.request(ledger_request)
    return ledger_response
```

After that, **in a new cell**, you will directly `await` the function that we just defined, why? The reason is simple, this way you will be running the `async` function and since **you expect** some result you will be waiting for it.

```
# Execute the function and wait for the response
response = await fetch_ledger_data()
print(response)
```

By this, your `async` function, you should be able to interact with `xrpl` library, without running into problems with the `asyncio` related errors.

When it comes to `AttributeError` which you mentioned, it's more likely to be an issue which is not related to `asyncio` and it might indicate a problem with the library or network request. (I can't really help here, I would need more context).

**NEW UPDATE:**
I got this running by usage of `nest_asyncio`, you executed the following in new cell:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

You will have to update the code above to this:

```
async def fetch_ledger_data():
    client = JsonRpcClient("https://xrplcluster.com/")
    ledger_request = Ledger(ledger_index="validated", transactions=True)
    ledger_response = client.request(ledger_request)  # Removed 'await'
    return ledger_response
```

Becasue the `client.request` method is not designed to be awaited, you should call it without the await keyword.

Then you attempt this:

```
response = await fetch_ledger_data()
print(response)
```

**Response Summary (which I got):**

- Status: SUCCESS
- Ledger Index: 85408465
- Ledger Hash: [REDACTED]
- Total Coins: 99,987,960,274,971,725
- Close Time (UTC): 2024-Jan-20 15:53:40.000000000
- Transactions Included: [List of transaction hashes redacted for privacy]

**Btw. I don't say that this is perfect solution, but it indeed does get stuff running.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I get error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'. Also if I execute os.system('run -m fetch_ledger_data') I get sh: run: command not found. To be honest I am not familiar with this 'run' command.

Comment: I don’t understand, so you are not using IPython? Because %run command which I mentioned as part of the solution can be used only when using IPython - therefore the error that you are now Getting is completely understandable as it doesn’t understand how to run async code. Please, clarify if you are using IPython or standard Python, that way I will be able to provide you with troubleshooting the code. @codingknob

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebook (IPython). I posted the error message traceback in the  original post for your reference. Appreciate the feedback. Ty.

Comment: @codingknob I just updated my answer, look under **UPDATE 1:**. I hope this will clarify it, and I am sorry for confusing you with the %run command - I kind of got wrong context and decided to jump to a conclusion of what you're trying to achieve. Hopefully this will be more understandable now.

Comment: **UPDATE-2**: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop. I updated the original post with the traceback of the error.

Comment: @codingknob I got this script running and I explained in answer how did I achieve it, also I said it's not the perfect solution, but it gets you what you want - some might argue about this solution and it's totally valid because its use can complicate event loop management and might not align with the best practices or design philosophy of `asyncio`. Devs often prefer to structure their code to work within the constraints of `asyncio`'s standard behavior.

Comment: This latest update works; you are a rockstar! Thank you for all your help mate.